# Match string pattern with random start and/or end

Tags: regex, algorithm

Suppose i have the following construct:

```
pattern = 'RepeatingMessage'
searchString = 'Aai23epjsditssageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepAsdjigrjiegj'
```

How can i make a function that cuts

```
'ssageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRep'
```

reliably, so that start and end of the repeating message could be random?

so it could also be:

```
'sfdsfu338843ufsingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessafuaz8792afsmssage'
```

in the second string you cut

```
'ingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessa'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the pattern continuously only once in the string or could you have something like ´essageRepeatingMessageRepooooooageRepeatingMessageRe´?

Comment: Is there a minimum length that must be matched?  For instance, RepeatingMessage contains 'a', and your original string 'Aai23epjsditssageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepAsdjigrjiegj' contains 'a' in the 2nd position.  Why didn't these match?

Comment: yes lets say minimum characters are the whole pattern at least once

Answer (score 1):

I am basing this answer on an assumption that there is a minimum number of characters that MUST be matched.

Step 1: build a state machine to count the number of characters matched.  This state machine will be circular.  When building this state machine, each node should be indexed in an array.  For example:

```
Node Nr:  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    ...
Node   :  R -> e -> p -> e -> a -> t -> i -> n -> g -> ...
Index:
'R' -> Node 0
'e' -> Node 1, 3, ...
```

Then you shift between 2 states:

1. Not consuming: For each node in the index, feed the current letter and traverse until minimum length is reached.  If min len is reached, enter consuming state, else move to next letter.
2. Consuming:  Keep consuming until state machine breaks out.  Shift to not consuming state.

Tested code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RepeatingMatcher
{
    public static String match(String pattern, String input)
    {
        Map<Character, List<PatternNode>> index = PatternNode.buildPattern(pattern);
        
        StringBuilder filteredInput = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            List<PatternNode> idxl = index.get(c);
            if (idxl != null)
            {
                boolean looking = true;
                for (int j = 0; looking && j < idxl.size(); j ++)
                {
                    int matchCnt = idxl.get(j).consume(input, i, 0);
                    if (matchCnt >= pattern.length())
                    {
                        // - 1 because the for loop will increment it.
                        i += matchCnt - 1;
                        looking = false;
                    }
                }
                
                if (looking)
                {
                    filteredInput.append(c);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filteredInput.append(c);
            }
        }
        
        return filteredInput.toString();
    }

    private static class PatternNode
    {
        private final char patternChar;
        private PatternNode next;

        PatternNode(char patternChar)
        {
            this.patternChar = patternChar;
        }

        int consume(String s, int idx, int cnt)
        {
            if (patternChar == s.charAt(idx))
            {
                cnt = cnt + 1;
                if (next != null)
                {
                    cnt = next.consume(s, idx + 1, cnt);
                }
            }

            return cnt;
        }

        static Map<Character, List<PatternNode>> buildPattern(String pattern)
        {
            Map<Character, List<PatternNode>> index = new HashMap<>();

            char c = pattern.charAt(0);
            PatternNode root = new PatternNode(c);
            List<PatternNode> idxl = index.getOrDefault(c, new ArrayList<>());
            index.put(c, idxl);
            idxl.add(root);
            PatternNode curr = root;
            for (int i = 1; i < pattern.length(); i++)
            {
                c = pattern.charAt(i);
                curr.next = new PatternNode(c);
                curr = curr.next;
                idxl = index.getOrDefault(c, new ArrayList<>());
                index.put(c, idxl);
                idxl.add(curr);
            }
            curr.next = root;

            return index;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes lets say minimum characters are the whole pattern.
can you give any code which would resemble this in any language you like? i get the concept but ill probably struggle implementing it

Comment: hey, i tried your code but couldnt get it to work. i did a script that does it for me now. i post it in an answer

Comment: I tested it and fixed a few typos (swapped input and pattern in 2 or 3 places) and an off-by-1 error.  It works well now, although I expected you to debug that much.

Answer (score 1):

The question contains the regex tag. I wouldn't entirely *suggest* this method based on your use case, but I solved it anyway. Here it is in a simpler, more readable regex for the key "word":

```
((((w)?o)?r)?d)?(word)+(w(o(r(d)?)?)?)?
```

Here is the full regex to solve the problem in the question:

```
((((((((((((((((R)?e)?p)?e)?a)?t)?i)?n)?g)?M)?e)?s)?s)?a)?g)?e)?(RepeatingMessage)+(R(e(p(e(a(t(i(n(g(M(e(s(s(a(g(e)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

Comment: This is nice, it may work well creating a function that generates the regex for a particular string. Although it does fail for cases like "epeatingMessa" when the full string does not appear.

Comment: If that's the desired behaviour, you could replace the the central "+" with a "*"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks for all replies. I could not get the java code to work for me, but i made a simple script that seems to work for this. It searches forward and reverse from the pattern indexes, check it out: (powershell)

```
function Match-Pattern {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]
        $Pattern,
        [string]
        $SearchString
    )
    
    begin {
        $patternRev = ([regex]::Matches($pattern, '.', 'RightToLeft') | 
            ForEach-Object { $_.value }) -join ''

        "Searching for all pattern occurances (with varying starts/ends):"
        "$Pattern`n"
        "in search string:"
        "$SearchString`n"

        $workingString = $SearchString
        while ($workingString.Contains($pattern)) {
            # get first starting point of repeat (min length is pattern length)
            $startIndexPattern = $workingString.IndexOf($pattern)
            # search behind for starting index
            $i = 1
            while ($workingString[$startIndexPattern - $i] -eq $patternRev[$i - 1]) {
                $startIndex = $startIndexPattern - $i
                $i++
            }
            # find last index of first pattern repetition
            $i = 1
            $multiplier = 0
            while ($workingString[$startIndexPattern + $pattern.Length * $multiplier - 1 + $i] -eq $pattern[$i - 1]) {
                $lastPatternStartIndex = $startIndexPattern + $pattern.Length * $multiplier - 1 + $i
                if ($i -eq $pattern.Length) {
                    $multiplier++
                    $i = 1
                } else {
                    $i++
                }
            }
            # $lastPatternStartIndex = $workingString.LastIndexOf($pattern)
            $lastPatternStartIndex++
            # cut string with indexes we found
            $substringLength = $lastPatternStartIndex - $startIndex
            $substring = $workingString.Substring($startIndex, $substringLength)

            "Found:"
            "$substring`n"

            "Cutting from workingString..:"
            $workingString = $workingString.Remove($workingString.IndexOf($substring),$substring.Length)
            "$workingString`n"
        }
    }
}

Match-Pattern -Pattern 'RepeatingMessage' `
    -SearchString @'
Aai23epjsditssageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepAsdjigrjiegj
Aai23epjsditssapeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessagcAsdjigrjiegj
Aai23epjsgeRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeatingMessageRepeaAsdjigrjiegj
'@
```